# Remove array from json array wrt if condition in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How to remove an array from json array in react js. I tried something like this. but not working

Now the response is directly set to atate as follows

```
let { newData} = response;
```

please help to filter item. Either from response or from state variable

```
response.map((res, index) => {
    if (res.status==1) {
    res.splice(index, 1) // remove element
};
})
```

response is  [object Object] when i alerted

```
[
{id:1, status:1},
{id:2, status:0},
{id:3, status:1},
]
```

Comment: 1. Do not use `.map` for simple iteration if you're not doing a mapping operation. Use `forEach`, a normal loop or an iteration method appropriate for the operation. 2. You're iterating forward through the indexes and splicing, which *modifies the array you work on*. So, if you're on index `1` and remove it, you'd move to index `2` *which used to be index `3`. You're skipping an item. This is even worse in iteration methods.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried the example you said about removing even numbers from [1,2,3,4,5] using splice and i got the expected result as [1,3,5]. So what is the problem you are pointing to?

Comment: @Tick20 wait, just tried it myself. Weird, it works with `splice`. I was definitely under the impression it would be skipping indeces. It you do `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; arr.forEach((item, i) => a.shift())` you do end up skipping items and `arr` is left as `[ 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` instead of just being empty. I expected a similar thing to happen with `splice`.

Comment: hmm, then let me post back the solution :)

Comment: let { newData} = response -> That is destructuring, which means that your response object would have to have a newData field for that to work. What does your entire response object look like? You said in the last portion of your question that it is just an array of objects with id's and status's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter instead of map and filter out the unwanted object/s.

```
const filteredArray = response.filter((res) => res.status !== 1);
```

Please just be aware that this will create a new array and not mutate your original array.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. It neither shows error in console nor working.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new one of Array, You can try..

```
let temp = []
response.forEach((res, index) => {
    if (res.status !== 1) {
        temp.push(res)
    }
})
```

Comment: Please don't use `.map` for simple iteration. You're not doing a mapping operation here. You should be using `.filter` to do this task or at the very least `forEach` (or a loop)

Comment: sorry, that statement I just copy from original. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use the filter method, or if you still want to use the splice, It should be response.splice
**Note: Using the splice approach is wrong as pointed out by @VLAZ, as it shifts the elements but the indexing by forEach will continue irrespective of the elements spliced off.**

```js
   var response = [
    {id:1, status:1},
    {id:2, status:0},
    {id:3, status:1},
    ]
    
    
    response.forEach((res, index) => {
        if (res.status==1) {
        response.splice(index, 1) // remove element
    };
    })
    
    console.log(response);
```

Comment: Wait...sorry to bother you again but turns out I was right. The example just *happened* to work. It's not an accumulative off by one, it's just off by one. [Here is an example to illustrate this](https://jsbin.com/goyumirabo/1/edit?js,console). When an even number is removed, the *next one* is skipped over. So if you have alternating numbers like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` that works because you visit `1` -> `2` -> `4`. But if you have two items that match the filter next to each other, only one is removed.

Comment: @VLAZ i am actually confused by the output produced by your code, i am going through it, thanks

Comment: Maybe [this example helps](https://jsbin.com/rataretocu/1/edit?js,console). I've changed double even numbers to number, then string. The log shows the strings are never traversed by the `forEach`. When index `1` is removed, you shift everything back, `"a"` becomes the new index `1` but then `forEach` goes to (the new) index `2` thus going over the values `1` -> `2` -> `3` and skipping `"a"`. The same thing happens with every other index that matches the filter - if it's removed, the *next* element goes in its place but `forEach` just goes to the next index after the shift has happened.